# Get URL parameter for crit use Spring MVC Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I want to be list out all my users with criteria of where id = formId. The code is working but just that it list out all the users instead of being filtered by formId. Please tell me where i did wrongly. Do tell me if you need any more info to solve this!

controller

*url = http://localhost:8080/User/Panda?Id=1

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/{name}?Id={id}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listClinicUser(ModelMap model, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {      
    logger.info("Users List Page - Id = " + id);

    List<User> user = service.findAllUsers(id); 
    model.addAttribute("users", user);   

    return "user/list";
}
```

Service

```
public List<User> findAllUsers(Integer id) {
    return dao.findAllUsers(id);
}
```

DAO Class

```
public interface UserDao {

    List<User> findAllUsers(Integer id);
}
```

*DAOImpl Class

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<User> findAllUsers(Integer id) {
    Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("formId",id));
    crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    List<User> users = (List<Usert>) crit.list();

    return users;
}
```

*for createEntityCriteria() i created in another class call abstractDao and extends to it.

```
private final Class<T> persistentClass;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public AbstractDao(){ 
    this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
}

protected Criteria createEntityCriteria(){
    return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
}
```

Class Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="formId", nullable=false)
    private Integer formId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME", nullable=false)
    private String lastName;

    public Integer getFormId() {
        return formId;
    }

    public void setFormId(Integer formId) {
        this.formId= formId;
    }

...

}
```

Comment: Add User entity class as well.

Comment: @StanislavL Added in!

Comment: Looks fine as far as I can see. Could you provide more info - dao code? createEntityCriteria(); ?

Comment: @StanislavL i added in but there are not much codes related to this method. I hope it helps!

Comment: I see no problems with the posted code...

Comment: @StanislavL oh no.. thanks for you help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

```
value = {"/{name}?Id={id}" }
```

This is wrong way to extract URL param. If you want to get URL param, you should pass it to your method using `@RequestParam` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/{name}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listClinicUser(ModelMap model, @RequestParam("Id") Integer id) {  
    //...
}
```

Spring automatically pass value that you need. For example in case of `?Id=1` Spring will pass 1 to your controller

Comment: if i remove my id, do i need to remove from the url as well?

Comment: you can try the code above to see that it will be the same result as earlier

Comment: I tried to rerun my original code and it's working now. Thanks for the help thought.

Answer (score 0):

In your url `/{name}` is a path variable and is annotated with `@PathVariable` like in:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/bar/{name}", method = GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getBarByName(@PathVariable String name) { ... }
```

And `?Id=id` is a request parameter and is annotated wiht `@RequestParam` so if we map to url like this one:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/foo/bar?id=100
```

we do it like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo/bar", method = GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getBarById(@RequestParam("id") Integer id) { ... }
```

So to combine them to map to your url:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/{name}" }, params = "id", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listClinicUser(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String name, @RequestParam("id" Integer id)) { ... }
```